# How to make a series of asynchronous calls and then use the value returned by first thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-2.0

I want to make asynchronous calls and then process the value returned by first thread. **I don't want to use Parallel library.** I can just use .Net 2.0. I have written the following program which should suffice my requirements. But can someone please point out if there is a better solution? Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
{
    private static Worker _worker2;
    private static Worker _worker3;
    private static Worker _worker4;
    private static Worker _worker1;
    delegate void DoWorkDelegate(object param);

    private static Worker _firstReturnedWorker = null;
    private static object lockObject = new object();

    public static void Main()
    {
        _worker1 = new Worker();
        _worker2 = new Worker();
        _worker3 = new Worker();
        _worker4 = new Worker();

        int i = 10;
        DoWorkDelegate d1 = new DoWorkDelegate(_worker1.OnDoWork);
        d1.BeginInvoke(1, OnThreadReturned, ++i);

        DoWorkDelegate d2 = new DoWorkDelegate(_worker2.OnDoWork);
        d2.BeginInvoke(2, OnThreadReturned, ++i);

        DoWorkDelegate d3 = new DoWorkDelegate(_worker3.OnDoWork);
        d3.BeginInvoke(3, OnThreadReturned, ++i);

        DoWorkDelegate d4 = new DoWorkDelegate(_worker4.OnDoWork);
        d4.BeginInvoke(4, OnThreadReturned, ++i);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    private static void OnThreadReturned(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            if (_firstReturnedWorker == null)
            {                    
                var workerIdentifier = (int)ar.AsyncState;
                switch (workerIdentifier)
                {
                    case 11:
                        _firstReturnedWorker = _worker1;
                        break;
                    case 12:
                        _firstReturnedWorker = _worker2;
                        break;
                    case 13:
                        _firstReturnedWorker = _worker3;
                        break;
                    case 14:
                        _firstReturnedWorker = _worker4;
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("First result received was {0}", _firstReturnedWorker.ReturnedValue);
    }
}

public class Worker
{
    public string ReturnedValue { get; private set; }

    public void OnDoWork(object value)
    {
        ReturnedValue = Process((int)value);
    }

    private string Process(int numberToProcess)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} was processed by {1}", numberToProcess, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it should work, so ok so far.

You could clean it up a bit by passing the Worker instance objects as the `AsyncState` instead of the magic number. Then you wouldn't need the `switch` in `OnThreadReturned` either.

---

The alternative would be to put all the `IAsyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle`'s in an array and call `WaitHandle.WaitAny`. This is more overhead though, as the `WaitHandle`'s are created on demand, so won't be needed in your callback solution. They are actual kernel objects, so this can matter.

Comment: Using WaitHandler.WaitAny looks more graceful to me. But, once I get the handle. 
how do I identify which worker instance has to be used.


var arrOfHandles = new WaitHandle[] { ai1.AsyncWaitHandle, ai2.AsyncWaitHandle, ai3.AsyncWaitHandle, ai4.AsyncWaitHandle };
var index = WaitHandle.WaitAny(arrOfHandles);
var handle = arrOfHandles[index];

Comment: The index returned from `WaitHandle.WaitAny` is the index into the array of `WaitHandles` that you pass as a parameter. So if it returns `0`, you know that `_worker1` completed first.